How to change the timestamp format of percona mysql audit logs
I have a RHEL linux server where I have installed mysql percona and set the auditing.
The Queries received in the audit record has timestamp in below format.
{"audit_record":{"name":"Query","record":"179295580_2024-10-03T10:56:38","timestamp":"2024-10-03T10:57:54 UTC","command_class":"drop_table","connection_id":"2","status":0,"sqltext":"drop table DPT","user":"abc[abc] @ localhost []","host":"localhost","os_user":"","ip":"","db":""}}
In the above record , timestamp has UTC. ""timestamp":"2024-10-03T10:57:54 UTC","
And I want it in this format: "timestamp":"2024-10-03T10:57:54Z".
Basically I want to replace UTC with Z.
I tried changing the timezone of the server , but its no help.
Please help me with this.
Thankyou

I'm sorry, but need to point out that this questions has nothing to do with programming or sw development. This is about configuring a database product. The dba.stackexchange.com sister-site of SO is the right place for asking such questions.

@Shadow It is a coding question, because to change this format, one would need to change the code of Percona Server.

@BillKarwin I would say modify the code of a product like mysql is not really a standard programming question. I imagine the OP wanted to know how to change the configuration of mysql to accomplish the expected result. Judjing from the OP's reaction to your answer, that's the case. All in all, the answer is: upgrade to 8.0, which is not a programming answer to me.

Are you using Percona Server 5.7 or 8.0? I assume you're using 5.7, because I see in the code for Percona Server 5.7, the format is hard-coded with the 'UTC' suffix you show.
https://github.com/percona/percona-server/blob/release-5.7.44-51/plugin/audit_log/audit_log.c#L152
strftime(buf, buf_len, "%FT%T UTC", gmtime_r(&t, &tm));

But in Percona Server 8.0, it's hard-coded with the 'Z' suffix.
https://github.com/percona/percona-server/blob/8.0/plugin/audit_log/audit_log.cc#L150
strftime(buf, buf_len, "%FT%TZ", gmtime_r(&t, &tm));

So it should be in the format you want if you upgrade.
To change it in Percona Server 5.7, you'd have to patch the Percona Server source code and build it yourself.

Thank you Bill Karwin,
So you mean , If I install Percona server 8.0 , then by default the audit log format will be in this format: "timestamp":"2024-10-03T10:57:54Z".
right?
And there is no way to get the timestamp in this format '"timestamp":"2024-10-03T10:57:54Z". '    on percona version 5.7?

Yes, that's how I read the code. It's hard-coded. Meaning, there is no option or command to change it, without changing the code.
